# How to restore the console after a call to clear (similar to less)?

Tags: bash, command-line, python

How do I clear the the console window, then do something with it (move the cursor, write something somewhere) and then put it back how it was before?

Similar to how `less`, `vi` or `man`.

I've heard about a python module that accomplished this, but I forgot its name.

Comment: what "console window" is that? (`gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, `putty`, linux virtual terminal, etc). Try `tput smcup; tput cup "$((LINES/2))" "$((COLUMNS/2-2))"; echo -n LOL; read var; tput rmcup`

Comment: Do you talk about `clear` command?

Comment: maybe python's [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) interface

Comment: As @mosvy says, you want smcup and rmcup. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @mosvy Thanks. The `curses` module is what I was looking for.